# Regex exact match of multiple strings within string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an string of |DOGS|MAN|CAT| and I need to check that DOG and CAT exist in the string.

The input string is always split between pipes.

I have this at present:

```
((^|, )(?=.*\|DOG|\b.$)(?=.*\|CAT\b).*$)
```

This almost works, if my input string was |DOG|MAN|CAT| it is fine but as I have specified DOGS not DOG it should not match

Comment: Is your input string always pipe-delimited? I'm not entirely clear on what your possible inputs are.

Comment: `if (/^(?=.*\|CAT\|)(?=.*\|DOG\|)/.test("|" + s + "|") { return true; }`

Comment: yes, the input is always pipe separated.

Comment: Wiktor, this works exactly as intended, thank you

Answer (score 5):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/6xJ5Qy/1) might help you to create a group, where you can list all your desired target string in it using a <kbd>|</kbd> (OR), and you may not bound it from left and right, if possible:

```
\b(DOG|CAT|ANYTHING|ELSE|THAT|YOU|WISH)\b
```

[image: RegEX]

Comment: The first one works if needing to match either DOG or CAT which is another thing i need to do.  the second doesn't fit my needs as it matches CAT when in the pipes it is CATS. Thank you though, the first is usefule